# Pass a PHP array using json_encode to be read with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, json

After doing a mySQL query in a query.php file, I end up with an array in this format using the json_encode() function.

```
["A","B", "C"].
```

However, I'm not really sure about how to use this array with JavaScript on a separate HTML file. After doing some research, here's the script I was able to gather.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('query.php', function(data) {        
        if(data)
        {
            document.write(data);   
            alert('success');    
        }
        else
        {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

My question is, how do I go about copying that PHP array (shown above) into another array I can use with JavaScript? or what's the best alternative to the script shown between the tags?

Thank you

Comment: You need to use an ajax method (like `$.getJSON`) to do that.  Does what you have not work?

Comment: If you do everything correctly, then `data` **is** the array.

Comment: What's the extra period behind the JSON notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `query.php` echo the result like

```
echo json_encode($result_array); // Assume $result_array as array("A","B", "C")
```

In the `success` function you can use it like

```
    if(data)
    {
        alert(data[0]); // will alert A    
    }
```

or you can use

```
$.each(data, function(k, v){
    console.log(k + ' = ' + v ); // k is key/index and v is value
});
```

this will outout (in the console)

```
0 = A
1 = B
2 = C
```

[You can check this example](http://jsfiddle.net/U6MjQ/).

Answer (score 0):

Its just a simple function call: `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

You must echo the json encoded array on your PHP page or it won't work. Then you use the function you've found and on success you use a $.each loop to actually show the content.

See http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.be/2012/05/how-to-read-and-parse-json-using-jquery.html